# Reset UIGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: swift

For some reason the `reset` method is part of the Obj-C documentation, but not the Swift documentation.

How come there is a different, and how to cancel a gesture recognizer in Swift?

Comment: Hmmm good point... In Objective C, you have to import the `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h` header in your gesture subclass but it isn't visible in Swift

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this for now by adding a Bridging Header to your project and importing `#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>` however its currently a bug as you should be able to use `import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass` directly in swift